# AutoDiscover not working yet everything is configured correctly

Tags: autodiscovery, outlook-anywhere

I have Exch 2013 on Server 2012 R2, Everything is working fine. Outlook is connecting internally and externally, OWA working internally and externally. The problem is when i run Microsoft Connectivity Tests i get results failed for Outlook AutoDiscover/ Outlook Connectivity and ActiveSync AutoDiscover/ ActiveSync Connectivity yet it works fine. I have configured everything correctly but again it fails. Can anyone please let me know why its giving failed results when my Outlook Autodiscover and Outlook connectivity is working fine ? See image for details

[Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDnIW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to the numeric certificate installed on the server. It is not valid for the name "autodiscover.waqaskhattak.com".

If you try to access https://autodiscover.waqaskhattak.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml your browser will show you this warning :

autodiscover.waqaskhattak.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: mail.waqaskhattak.com, www.mail.waqaskhattak.com

Comment: But why it is not able to retrieve the autodiscover.xml using the autodiscover URL ? i have no concern if i get autodiscover warning. I want the autodiscover test connectivity to be successful

Comment: Because Microsoft Connectivity test always fail when the certificate is not accepted without warning. You will have the same behavior with a self signed certificate that has the correct name.

Comment: @MashalKhan: It really doesn't matter what you want or don't want. The test will fail if the certificate name doesn't match. - http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-2010-faq-autodiscover-names-ssl-certificate/

Comment: okay, does it means that my autodiscover url is configured correctly ? but it can not be retrieved unless certificate is valid ? if i install a valid certificate it will say that successfully retreived autodiscover.xml by URL ?

Comment: It would appear so.